# Another SQL ERROR 1064 (42000) : cant locate the error

Tags: mysql, sql

My code :

```
CREATE TABLE order(
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  contact varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  item text NOT NULL,
  amount varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  status varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  dateOrdered varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  dateDelivered varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

after i import this in GCP SQL i get :

> Import failed: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 74: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'order( id int(11) NOT
>   NULL, name varchar(32) NOT NULL, contact varchar(32)' at line 1 Import
>   error: exit status 1

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name of your table, order is a reserve word in mysql and that's why it shows error

```
CREATE TABLE orders
( 
id int(11) NOT NULL,
name varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
contact varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
address varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
email varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
item varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
amount varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
status varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
dateOrdered varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
dateDelivered varchar(32) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: In addition to your answer I want to say that he can put the name in quotes and it will work again. It will look like `\`order\``

Comment: @codtex, agreed with you fully, that was not poped into my head :)

Comment: i tried changing the name and that worked. Thanks Guys.

Comment: @HoliSappo, if it helped u then please mark it as answer

Comment: Also orders is a better name than order, because the table (hopefully) stores many orders.